# Session variable not getting in another inner file PHP

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have one login form when user give username and password it leads to `login.php` file

```
session_start();
if ( isset( $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] ) ) {  
    $user   = $_POST['username'] ;
    $pass   = $_POST['password'] ;
    $query  = " MY QUERY "; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('SQL ERROR:'.mysql_error()); 
    $row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);   
    if ($row) {         
        echo "query successfull wrote to DB";       
        unset($_SESSION);
        $userName = $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['userNameSession'] = $userName;
        $_SESSION['loginStatus']     = '1';
        header('location:admin/admin.php');
    }else{
        echo "unscccessful login";
        header('location:index.php');
    }
}
```

When I Try to print the session by `print_r($_SESSION)` from this  file.. it shows the session and its variable with values

```
Array ( [userNameSession] => full name [loginStatus] => 1 )
```

In my `admin/admin.php` (opens when successful login) wrote

```
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION);exit;
```

if try to print the session by `print_r($_SESSION)` it shows empty array as `Array()`

Please help.

Comment: Your `else{}` clause is gonna throw a error, you cannot echo any data out before a `header()`.

Comment: @Epodax thank you for your fast replay.. can u show how can i make it correct?

Comment: Remove the `echo "unscccessful login";` line

Comment: @Epodax I have removed the `echo` but result still same..not getting session variable in next page

Comment: Is your index.php file loading when error occured?

Comment: Actually in both paths of the if-statement the headers are already sent before reaching the header().

Comment: @ SajithaNilan & budwiser How can i solve this? can u plz show the corrected code

Comment: Did you try this echo $_SESSION['loginStatus']; ?

Comment: @SajithaNilan Yes.. i already tried.. but no hope

Comment: try this insterd of header <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;admin/admin.php' />. I dont know whether it work or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you make an `unset($_SESSION)`? This may cause the session variable is deleted but the session still exists.

If you want to clean `$_SESSION['LoginStatus']` and `$_SESSION['userNameSession']`, better clean one by one (although this is not necessary because you'll rewrite its value later):

```
unset($_SESSION['LoginStatus']);
unset($_SESSION['userNameSession']);
```

The code must be like this:

```
session_start();
if ( !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ) {  
    $user   = $_POST['username'] ;
    $pass   = $_POST['password'] ;
    $query  = " YOUR QUERY "; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('SQL ERROR:'.mysql_error());   
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {        
        //DELETE prints BEFORE header()!! -> echo "query successfull wrote to DB"; 
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        unset($_SESSION['userNameSession']);
        unset($_SESSION['loginStatus']);

        $userName = $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'];

        $_SESSION['userNameSession'] = $userName;
        $_SESSION['loginStatus']     = '1';

        header('location:admin/admin.php');
    }else{
        //DELETE prints BEFORE header()!! -> echo "unscccessful login";
        header('location:index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Wowww... Thats the problem is..... Now its correct.. I dint think of it. Thanks ypu soooo much...

Answer (score 1):

One important thing that you must notice:

**Don't echo before header.** I think your code should be like this:

```
session_start();
if ( isset( $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] ) ) {  
    $user   = $_POST['username'] ;
    $pass   = $_POST['password'] ;
    $query  = " MY QUERY "; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('SQL ERROR:'.mysql_error()); 
    $row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);   
    if ($row) {       
        unset($_SESSION);
        $userName = $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['userNameSession'] = $userName;
        $_SESSION['loginStatus']     = '1';
        header('location:admin/admin.php');
    }else{
        header('location:index.php');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will happen only if condition is false. How about the true part of the code.

Comment: @SajithaNilan No, it will happen on both conditions in op's code.